# Как отключить предупреждения #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS в VS 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как отключить предупреждения в VS 2017? Использование #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS в самом начале кода не помогает. Если поставить в свойствах препроцессора то получаю 100+ ошибок при компиляции.

Comment: Добавлять его надо выше любых детектив `include` включающих системные файлы

Comment: Не надо ее никуда добавлять. Также не забудьте включить предупреждения компилятора опцией /W4 и исправьте все проблемные места в вашем коде. Еще полезно прогонять код через статические анализаторы. Встроенный в студию в основном заточен на использование SAL аннотаций, но и от него может быть польза.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы ошибаетесь. Прекрасно работает и в начале кода, и в свойствах проекта. А что вы там напортачили в вашем случае - отсюда не видно.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Включите эту директиву в заголовок `stdafx.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Подойдет любой из упомянутых вами способов. и все они прекрасно работают. Но лучше не захламлять код нестандартными директивами, а сделать это в настройках проекта. Только в свойствах препроцессора надо писать `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, а не `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`.